# Use $VARIABLE as build task for Gradle plugin in Jenkins

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I am trying to make a Jenkins multiconf job to build a project in the debug and release modes. To that end, I created a custom matrix with a var `BUILD_MODE` with values "debug" and "release". Now I am trying to pass that value to the Gradle plugin: 
In "Execute shell" step i have the following:

```
GRADLE_TASK="assembleGoogle$(tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]' <<< ${BUILD_MODE:0:1})${BUILD_MODE:1}"
```

and in the Gradle step, the tasks are `clean $GRADLE_TASK`, but when the build runs, the variable is not replaced by its value. Is there a way I can trigger different Gradle tasks depending on the build mode (preferably without conditional builds).

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, you can use the ${BUILD_MODE} var, but not the vars set in the previous script. Luckily, Gradle is not case sensitive as far as the task names are concerned.

Comment: Do you any more about case-sensitivity in Jenkins Gradle task calls? I am getting a failed Jenkins job which tries to call a paramterised Gradle task using a lowercase instead of an uppercase and it cannot find the task. I can see it in Gradle which is odd...

Comment: I am not very good at Gradle, in my case, everything worked in a non-case-sensitive manner. Are you sure you don't have gradle tasks that become ambiguous when spelt in lowcase?